# There is a way to use boto3 paginator with multiple prefix?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

There is a way to use boto3 paginator to retrieve data from multiple different AWS S3 paths?

In the following example, I read all the data located under `folder/folder1`

```
paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Prefix="folder/folder1"
)
```

But what if I want to read all the data from `folder/folder1` and `folder/folder3`? Can it be done by using only one paginator instance at once?

Answer (score 0):

[The `ListObjectsV2` API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) takes one prefix.

If you want to list more than one prefix at once, make more than one API call concurrently or sequentially.